# Variable in page title?

Tags: php

I have a page that contains a DB query, If there is a county in the URL then I run another query.

```
<head>
    <title>Query results in $county</title>
</head>

...

if (isset($county)) {

    // If county is set
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND County = :county");

 } else {

     // Run another query

 }
```

I want to add the county in the page title if the county is set.  Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you're asking how to echo the variable: `<?php echo $county; ?>`.

Comment: Where is $county defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($county)) {
    echo "<title>Query results in $county</title>\n";
} else {
    echo "<title>Some other title</title>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Just make sure your php that sets `$county` comes before the start of your html, then change your `title` tag to this:

```
<title>Query results in <?php echo $county;?></title>
```

Edit: Although j08691's answer is more comprehensive.